# Logging transient failures when using EnableRetryOnFailure

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have program that controls industrial production equipment and is always performing tasks in a loop. Part of these tasks is checking values in an SQLServer database.

Now and then (a few times per day) we would get transient failures which caused the program to have to be manually restarted. To prevent this I have enabled the `EnableRetryOnFailure` option for `UseSqlServer`. The program now doesn't crash but I'd like to have logging of when such transient failures have occured and the retry mechanism had to be used.

How do I add logging specifically for these retries?

I assume I could create a custom `ExecutionStrategy` and override the OnRetry method. Does anyone have any example for this? Are there no better solutions?

```
services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString, o =>
    {
        o.EnableRetryOnFailure();
    });
});
```

Comment: Check [Logging - EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3). EF Core uses the logging infrastructure. You can configure what gets logged for each error category and where

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Any idea where I can find a list of what logging category it might be? Or could I find it in the source code of `ExecutionStrategy` what they log to?

Comment: The names are defined under the [DbLoggerCategory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbloggercategory?view=efcore-3.0) class.[Searching the source](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/master/src/EFCore/Diagnostics/CoreLoggerExtensions.cs#L775) is worth it because it shows that EF Core is using both logging and low-overhead event sources through [IDiagnosticsLogger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.idiagnosticslogger-1?view=efcore-3.0)

Comment: The event ID is stored in [CoreEventId.ExecutionStrategyRetrying](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.diagnostics.coreeventid.executionstrategyretrying?view=efcore-3.0)

Comment: [This EF Core test](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/blob/0d76bbf45a42148924b413ef8f37bf49c1ce10d3/test/EFCore.Specification.Tests/FixtureBase.cs) configures warnings by CoreEventID value through DbContextOptionsBuilder.